# How to create Dialog Box with Radio Buttons and return Value

Tags: c#, list, dialog, radio-button

I have a List of Objects. What I want to do:

Build a Dialog Box which shows a Radio Button for each element in the given List and returning the selected element/value by clicking on OK-Button.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in Winform? create a new Form and dynamically add controls

Comment: Create your own using win forms and use `DialogResult` for control.

Comment: @LeiYang is there a code example of a basic winform? or something easier like a message/prompt box?

Comment: why do you think message/prompt box is easier?

Comment: @LeiYang dont know. is there a code example of a basic winform?

Comment: if you specify what type of objects you have, i might give some example, there's no generic and universal ways.

Comment: Unless I don't understand what is the problem you are facing...it is even faster than looking for a solution on the web if you start by dragging a dialog in visual studio designer.

Comment: @LeiYang that would be nice! It is enough if it is a list of strings.

Comment: done, @dnks23, a little late

Answer (score 2):

OOps! I came back just to see there are already 2 answers! How ever, I want to post my version, which can build controls according to list of strings:

```
//dialog form
public partial class frmDialogcs : Form
{
    public string selectedString;

    //keep default constructor or not is fine
    public frmDialogcs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public frmDialogcs(IList<string> lst)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
        {
            RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
            rdb.Text = lst[i];
            rdb.Size = new Size(100, 30);
            this.Controls.Add(rdb);
            rdb.Location = new Point(20, 20 + 35 * i);
            rdb.CheckedChanged += (s, ee) =>
            {
                var r = s as RadioButton;
                if (r.Checked)
                    this.selectedString = r.Text;
            };
        }
    }
    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
    //in main form
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lst = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
        frmDialogcs dlg = new frmDialogcs(lst);
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string selected = dlg.selectedString;
            MessageBox.Show(selected);
        }
    }
```

Comment: does 'public frmDialogcs(IList<string> lst)' not need any return statement?

Comment: this is constructor, you just copy my code and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example of creating your own form and getting a value from it.

Form1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmTest frmTest = new frmTest();

        DialogResult dr = frmTest.ShowDialog();

        if(dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string value = frmTest.GetValue();
            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Form1 View:

[image: Form1]

```
public partial class frmTest : Form
{
    private string _value { get; set; }
    public frmTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }

    private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;

        this._value = radioButton.Text; // Assign the radio button text as value Ex: AAA
    }

    public string GetValue()
    {
        return this._value;
    }
}
```

You have to make sure that all radio buttons are using `radioButton_CheckedChanged` for the `CheckedChanged` event.

Form2 View:

[image: Form2]

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

build your own form and add a public variable "a string for example" called "Result"

```
public partial class YourDialog:Form
{
  public string Result = "";
  public YourDialog()
  {// add all the controls you need with the necessary handlers
   //add the OK button with an "On Click handler"
  }

  private void OK_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //set the Result value according to your controls
    this.hide();// will explain in the main form
  }

}

// in your main form
private string GetUserResult()
{
  YourDialog NewDialog = new YourDialog(); 
  NewDialog.ShowDialog();//that's why you only have to hide it and not close it before getting the result

  string Result = NewDialog.Result;
  NewDialog.Close();  
  return Result;
}
```